# Nidified mysqli_fetch_assoc while

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movie_list WHERE id=$id";
 $result_q = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_q);

 if ($row['movie_type'] == 'E' || $row['movie_type'] == 'S'){
    $query_serie = "SELECT * FROM movie_list WHERE id_serie=$row[id_serie]";
    $result_q_serie = mysqli_query($conn, $query_serie);


    $query_serie_cont = "SELECT serie_number FROM movie_list WHERE id_serie = $row[id_serie] AND serie_number IS NOT null GROUP BY serie_number";
    $result_q_serie_cont = mysqli_query($conn, $query_serie_cont);


[...]


<?php
  while($row_serie_cont = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_q_serie_cont)){ ?>
    <li>
      <a class="collapsible-header collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-teal bold">Season <?php echo $row_serie_cont['serie_number']?></a>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          <ul>
          <?php
            while($row_serie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_q_serie)){ 
              if ($row_serie['serie_number'] == $row_serie_cont['serie_number']){
                echo "<li><a href=player.php?id=".$row_serie['id'].">".$row_serie['episode_number']."</a></li>";
              }
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";
  }
?>
   </li>
```

It works perfect the first while but the second time the while($row_serie) variable are missing. Debugging the page I see the $row_serie variable disappear after completed all the first while($row_serie_cont) but not reappearing at all when it was triggered the second time.

What I've miss in the code?

Comment: where is your mysql query???

Comment: i omit it because isn't important for the question.
the query is right i'm sure

Comment: submit your full code we try to help you

Comment: added the query on the code part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that use **mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);** do the trick the right way.

Answer (score 0):

you close `li` after loop make it correct

```
while($row_serie_cont = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_q_serie_cont)){ ?>
    <li>
      <a class="collapsible-header collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-teal bold">Season <?php echo $row_serie_cont['serie_number']?></a>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          <ul>
          <?php
            while($row_serie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_q_serie)){ 
              if ($row_serie['serie_number'] == $row_serie_cont['serie_number']){
                echo "<li><a href=player.php?id=".$row_serie['id'].">".$row_serie['episode_number']."</a></li>";
              }
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";
 echo "</li>"// inside the loop
  }
?>
```

Comment: you are right but this doesn't fix the code. the problem is on the while part.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that insert  `$result_q_serie = mysqli_query($conn, $query_serie);`into the second while do the trick.

I don't understand why i need to repopulate result_q_serie is needed but now it works.

If someone can propose a better solution I'm hearing

```
<?php
            while($row_serie_cont = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_q_serie_cont)){ ?>
    <li class="no-padding">
    <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
        <li>
        <a class="collapsible-header collapsible-header waves-effect waves-teal bold">Season <?php echo $row_serie_cont['serie_number']?>
        </a>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
                <?php
                                    $result_q_serie = mysqli_query($conn, $query_serie);
                                    while($row_serie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_q_serie)){ 
                                        if ($row_serie['serie_number'] == $row_serie_cont['serie_number']){
                                            echo "<li>
                <a href=player.php?id=".$row_serie['id'].">".$row_serie['episode_number']."</a></li>
                "; } } echo "
            </ul>
            "; echo "
        </div>
                </li>


    </ul>
    </li>
        "; } ?>
        </ul>
```